# conditional str_replace based on matching regex within mutate?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr

For any entries of the column "district" that match `regex("[:alpha:]{2}AL")`, I would like to replace the "AL" with "01".

For example:

```
df <- tibble(district = c("NY14", "MT01", "MTAL", "PA10", "KS02", "NDAL", "ND01", "AL02", "AL01"))
```

I tried:

```
  df %>% mutate(district=replace(district, 
                          str_detect(district, regex("[:alpha:]{2}AL")), 
                          str_replace(district,"AL","01")))
```

and

```
  df %>% mutate(district=replace(district, 
                          str_detect(district, regex("[:alpha:]{2}AL")), 
                          paste(str_sub(district, start = 1, end = 2),"01",sep = ""))
```

but there is a vectorization problem.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ok?

```
str_replace_all(string=df$district,
                pattern="(\\w{2})AL",
                replacement="\\101")
```

I replaced the regex with `\\w`, a word character: https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

I am using `\\1` to indicate replace the string with the first captured region, which is captured in the `(\\w{2})` so keep the first 2 letters then add the 01

Comment: yes! thanks! thanks for the reminder about *backreferences* https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `replace` to `ifelse`

```
ifelse( str_detect(df$district, regex("[:alpha:]{2}AL")), 
         str_replace(df$district,"AL","01"),df$district)
```